# Lambert-Conic projection - GPS of corners

Tags: coordinate-system, reprojection-mathematics, lambert-conformal-conic

I have an 2D image in Lambert-Conic projection. I know the bounding box of coordinates, but I want to calculate the coordinates of image corners. They don't have to be the same as bounding box. How can I achieve this?

On the picture, the black dots are corners of 2D image in Lambert-Conic projection. The entire image below represents the bounding box as in "no projection". It can be seen that the max latitude does not correspond to any point directly.

[image]

The effect can be seen in the below pictures. Left (red) is image in Lambert projection - it is square but corners are not of the same latitude / longitude. On the right (blue) the image is reprojected to the "no-projection" and I am looking for coordinated of the blue corners - that are same as black dots in above image.

[image]

Comment: In the past, I added fourteen vertices between each "corner" (61 vertices in the "rectangle") before projecting, then added a small cushion to be sure my projected canvas extent was valid.

Comment: @Vince With your solution, I can compute bounding box, but I already have bounding box. I need the "image" corners (black dots)

Comment: It's easier to extract that from the NODATA/data boundary.

Comment: The line across the top or bottom is a line of constant latitude and the sides are constant longitude. It just an artifact of the projection that makes them look curved

Comment: @IanTurton See my edit. I have the red input data with boudning box and I want to get corners of projected blue area. They are not constant because of curved lines in Lambert (red).